# setFormulasR1C1 possible without #ERROR!?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use setFormulasR1C1 to copy formulas to a newly created row via a script, as it seems R1C1 is the only way to have the formulas continue dynamic changes.

But this is resulting in #ERROR!'s nearly every cell **including** blank cells.

Is there not a way to do this using R1C1?

I'm gathering it's because my formulas aren't in R1C1 format yet but given that the **empty cells** don't even work it hasn't motivated me to convert these formulas yet.

Example of forumla that's producing #ERROR! when copied down using R1C1.

```
=IF(C113="text",D112+(1.5/24),(IF(OR(C113="",C113="*enter text*"),"",C113-((INDIRECT("D"&AZ113))/24))))
```

The only one that doesn't have an error is a fully locked formula

```
=$AS$89
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the sheet?

Comment: Show the code you're using as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy a range from one location to another the formula in the original range will be changed to reflect the new location, just like cut and paste

A1 = 1, B1 = 2, C1 = =A1+B1 will be 3

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1,3,1,1);
range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(2,3,1,1));
```

A2 = 3, B2 = 4, C2 = =A2+B2 will be 7

Comment: copyTo is working now! thank you. not sure why I couldn't get copyTo to work before but it is going the trick now just like copypaste.

Comment: I guess the only thing separating this from ideal is it won't copy formulas only and still copy them down without copying any values, still unsure how to do this, but other than that it's good to go cheers.

Comment: If you copy the whole row the values and formulas will be copied using copyTo.  If you use getValues() and setValues() any formulas in the range are ignored and the value for that cell will be blank.  Likewise for gerFormulas()/setFormulas() any values in that range are ignored and the formula for that cell will be blank.